# Checking words in a line of text file are bold/italic using java

Tags: java, file

I need to store bold,italic words for further processing.Following is program:

```
    package JavaApplication14;
    import java.io.*;
    public class file_handling {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String s="a.txt";
        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\"+s;
`
`        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line;
        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String words[]=line.split(" ");
                System.out.println(line);
                int i=0;
                for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                    {
                        System.out.println(words[i]);
                    };                        
                }  
            }       
            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

I need to check if words in words[] array are bold or italic. If the code seems incorrect is there any other way to do this program?

Comment: None of the words will be bold or italic, since you're reading a plain text file. Plain text files have no formatting. (Unless you're abusing certain unicode chars, which you're almost certainly not...)

Answer (score 1):

There are no bold or italic characters in a *.txt file, as mk said.

Furthermore, when you do for loops, you should avoid initialising int i before starting the loop.

Instead of that:

```
int i = 0
for (i = 0; i<words.length; i++) { ...
```

you should do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i<words.length; i++) { ...
```

That way you can re-use the variable i in other loops.